# jQuery mobile page/scrolling behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have a question for a jQuery/jQuery Mobile expert/ninja.

I have a page using jQuery Mobile with a form on it and I notice that when I click a button or link it often does not respond.

I notice that if I scroll it then responds.

Is this a default behaviour of jQuery Mobile?

If so what is it called and can it be disabled?

Comment: Post the form's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I know enough about jQuery Mobile to not use it. I found it to be excruciatingly slow.  And I spent too much time on styling work-arounds.

I would doubt that is the default behavior. The question is, is it called a bug or a feature?

Putting that aside, jQuery Mobile Buttons are anchors `<a>` that are styled to resemble buttons.  While both `<button>` and `<a>` anchors are made to be clicked, the button's purpose in life is to generate a click event.  Were the anchor acts differently with navigation as its purpose.

The solution may be to use `<button>` and add an event listener when the button's purpose is to call a javaScript/jQuery routine rather than use its class to define functionality.

This is a common technique.  Even though it is a discouraged practice by the guys that write Browser Code (e.g MDN).  I find it to be the most common practice that makes a site very dysfunctional when it fails.  Especially when it's the "Checkout" link that fails.

```
<a onclick="jsfunction()" href="#">
```

This is pretty much the equivalent of how jQuery Mobile does links.

I would need to see the `<form>` to get a handle on what is going wrong.